# Error “This Page Can’t be displayed” when Recording in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Scenario: After searching an account, I need to click on one of the menu on the left navigation bar that opens an IFrame.

When I do it manually, it works fine.
But when I do it during recording in JMeter the error “This Page Can’t be displayed”  is being displayed.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the browser which has separate proxy/certificates configuration. A good choice is [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
2. Make sure to [clear ALL your browsing data](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic) prior to recording. You will have to [re-install JMeter's self-signed certificate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) after this
3. Check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file for any suspicious entries
4. If you're behind the corporate firewall/proxy you will have to [make JMeter aware of this firewall](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)
5. You can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) for recording, it's non-invasive solution and you will not have to worry about proxies and certificates.